# Here SDK: How to implement a CustomDataSource

Tags: android, here-api

Is it possible to implement a CustomDataSource to use the default PositionIndicator? The documentation don't gives me any clue if there is a Interface i can implement. I only found the classes LocationDataSource and LocationDataSourceHERE which i could extend. But there is no documentation how to use these classes if i want to use a custom datasource.

Answer (score 0):

The position indicator is directly integrated into the SDK positioning interfaces. If you implement a LocationDataSource interface and start it via PostioningManager it will update the position indicator. However note that your custom data source position will ALSO be used for all other SDK operations related to positioning. EG: Guidance.

Comment: And thats what i want. But i simply don't know what i have to do to get the DataSource to work. The api-documentation is no big help to me.